# BIRT ODA Plugin Accessing Data Set Filter

Tags: birt

I have a custom BIRT data source that uses the BIRT Open Data Access (ODA) API similar to the example described in chapter 20 of the book "Integrating and Extending BIRT". However, I've been unable to find any way to pass data set filters to my custom data source.

When I go to run a query in BIRT, it seems to be using the following sequence of events:

1. BIRT requests all data from my plugin.
2. BIRT then applies the filters to the resultset.

So if a user wants to generate a report on April 2013 sales, the BIRT data source plugin is pulling all sales data from the server to the client and then applying the filter to limit to April 2013.

I searched on this issue and came [across a similar thread in the BIRT forums from 2009](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/17363/), in that thread, Lina Chan stated that:

> I'm afraid the "Filters" defined in BIRT Data Set Editor is something 
>   defined purely in the BIRT host, and are not visible to an ODA data 
>   provider. In other words, the BIRT filters' processing is handled by the 
>   BIRT data engine, and are not pushed down to an ODA runtime driver.

Based on that answer, I'm assuming that it is not possible to do this as of the BIRT version in 2009. Is that answer still correct with today's BIRT version?

Or is there another workaround? It seems odd that BIRT would build such a pluggable interface for data sources, but provide no mechanism to filter the data coming back from the data source.

Comment: What type of data source are you accessing - relational, flatfile ...?

Comment: @MarkBannister - The data source is a pentaho data source (see https://code.google.com/p/birt-pentahometadata-plugin/). However, the question is more general. I'm trying to determine if ANY data source in a BIRT plugin can access the BIRT filters page.

Comment: @David - I have zero knowledge about pentaho, so just to rule out the obvious.  You are saying that unlike using a SQL database with pentaho you are not able to insert any criteria in to your data query?

Comment: @JamesJenkins - Pentaho has the capacity to insert criteria into its queries. However, the question is about whether a BIRT ODA Plugin can access the BIRT criteria. If the BIRT ODA Plugin can't access the BIRT criteria, then pentaho obviously can't filter the request from BIRT if it doesn't know what filters BIRT wants to apply. BIRT calls pentaho to retrieve the data to be displayed.